# Create a variable from a URL's Query String

Tags: url, variable

How can I create a variable that is pulled from a URL like the one below?

eg: http://www.example.com/page.php?Item_ID=774&score=42

Need to pull the number "42" from the url and placed into a form which is then emailed by the user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [**Mo' Variables**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables). It will give you access to GET variables like this `{get:your_key}` (in your case `{get:score}`).

Mo' Variables has many other uses, as well!

Comment: @alex Is using this plugin the only way to achieve this?

Comment: If we're talking templates... your alternative options are 1) possibly another plugin with similar function, or 2) make your own [plugin](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/plugins.html). 3) you *could* enable PHP in the template and use some PHP, but you are better off making a simple plugin instead or just using Mo' Variables.